# How do you write integration tests for Firestore on Unity?

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore, mocking

I have a Unity3D app backed by a Firebase/Firestore database.

Firebase provides a [Local Emulator Suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) for testing, but [it is not supported on Unity](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/719).

It seems the only way to test logic which uses Firestore is to either:

1. Use a real, test-only database and clear it on each SetUp
2. Mock out all usages of Firestore

(2) seems error-prone and like I'm reinventing the wheel. (1) seems both dangerous and slow. Is there another widely-supported option I'm missing?

Comment: Also posted on: https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/tPhBmjzWu7s

Comment: Right now there is no official way on how to implement integration test for Firestore on Unity. I suggest you to follow this github [feature request](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/868) in which they discuss how to implement the Local Emulator of Firebase in Unity for further updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emulator suite is now supported. See https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/719#issuecomment-938759588

To use the emulator, run

```
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance;
firestore.Settings.Host = "localhost:8080";
firestore.Settings.SslEnabled = false;
```

Make sure you use this code in each assembly used. Many tutorials have the tests run in a separate assembly as the rest of your code. If your architecture is similar, you will need the above code in each assembly. Specifically, be sure to call this code both in your test assembly when accessing `FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance`, and in your game code, since `FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance` exists once per process (i.e. once per assembly).